# Display local-language data in JSON?

Tags: mysql, json, utf-8

Here is the Data in my MySQL DB
[image]

And the corresponding PHP code to retrieve it

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `states` ORDER BY `NAME`";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

$json_response = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $field_info = mysqli_fetch_fields($result);
    foreach ($field_info as $value) {
        $row_array[$value->name] = $row[$value->name];
    }
    array_push($json_response, $row_array);
}
echo json_encode($json_response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

JSON output is printing ???? instead of `actual text`

Help ! 
Here is JSON Output
[image: JSON Output]

Comment: What is your database encoding? This is probably an encoding mismatch. You might want to try converting it to UTF-8 before the `json_encode`.

Comment: I tried, no luck....

Comment: Have you tried without `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`?

Comment: Modified this `echo json_encode(utf8_encode($json_response));`
``
`Warning: utf8_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given `

Comment: As with virtually every question of this type: **database connection encoding!** See the duplicate. If that doesn't help, update your question addressing this issue.

Comment: Hey @deceze, thanks for your reply, that was very informative, however i tried to follow the said procedure, added `mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8mb4');` but no change.
[Here](http://imgur.com/H5kjJpJ) is my DB.